# Laravel Service Provider Class Not Found — Server Specific Issue

Tags: laravel, namespaces, package

I'm creating a custom package for Laravel 5, and have run into the problem where Laravel is having trouble finding the service provider for this, but only on a specific server. Locally, I'm running this under Vagrant using the Homestead box, and it's working fine. Using git to push it to a dreamhost VPS (Ubuntu), it's giving me the error that it can't the class Figoliquinn\Quickbooksconnect\QuickbooksconnectServiceProvider. It feels like a namespace issue to me because it's working differently on different environments, but I haven't been able to track down the cause.

The folder structure for the package is (from the laravel root):

```
* packages
|--* figoliquinn
   |--* quickbooksconnect
   |--* src
      |--* QuickbooksconnectServiceProvider.php
```

**QuickbooksconnectServiceProvider.php**

```
    <?php namespace Figoliquinn\Quickbooksconnect;

use Figoliquinn\Quickbooksconnect;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class QuickbooksconnectServiceprovider extends ServiceProvider {


    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {   
        // Get the views we'll need
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'quickbooksconnect');

        // Register our controller and routes
        $this->app->router->group(['namespace' => 'Figoliquinn\Quickbooksconnect\Controllers'],
        function(){
            require __DIR__.'/routes.php';
        });
    }


    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }

}
```

Here's what my composer.json file looks like in the Laravel root:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "~5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Figoliquinn\\Quickbooksconnect\\": "packages/figoliquinn/quickbooksconnect/src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

And then when adding this in config/app.php, this looks like (abbreviated just to the providers section):

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Figoliquinn\Quickbooksconnect\QuickbooksConnectServiceProvider',

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        'App\Providers\MacrosServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\CurrentOrgServiceProvider',

    ],
```

Any suggestions on something I might have overlooked?

Comment: Have you dumped your autoloader?

Comment: Yep. The Figoliquinn namespace is also showing up within vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php.

Comment: Hmm. Are you doing this on the production end as well? The autoloader is usually in the vendor folder which is automatically added to .gitignore

Comment: Yep, which is why it was feeling pretty strange. Ran composer dump-autoload within the root of the laravel directory multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being really stupid on my part. I'd included more or less an SDK I was try to integrate into a package, and that SDK had a .gitignore file that was causing some issues pushing stuff around. Removing that did the trick.